# Target API Error

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, rest

I have done a lot of research but I didn't found solution.
My problem is when I run this code it causes an error:

> "Required Boolean but found integer"

I want to connect REST API with Android but my web api is in asp.net

my code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() 
{               
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {  
      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);    
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you missing a "="? which should be `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT== Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB`?

Comment: Thanks bro its now working i am missing == this